# How do I stop a web browser from openning the same website everytime I start it?

Tags: windows, browser

**Context:** I have three web browsers installed on my Windows 10 computer which are Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.

**Problem:** Whichever browser I newly open, they all start with this website:http://007eecfcfedlkh.jumpkj.chuairan.com/index.html

**How it happened:** I clicked a link on a website yesterday and it automatically downloaded several applications and automatically installed themselves without showing any instructions to install them.

**Thing I have tried:** I have reset the browser **On startup** setting to open my homepage, but it still opens with the aforementioned weird URL.

**Thing that may help:** Opera browser is very considerate cause it has this option regarding the **On startup** setting, which is ***Ask me when Opera is started by a shortcut specifying an URL***.

**Analysis and need your help:** Usually, I start a browser by clicking on the shortcut in Windows **start menu**, or the shortcut in **desktop**. This worked normally until the problem appeared. According to **Thing that may help**, this hostile URL must reside somewhere. *Where can I find this unwelcoming shortcut on my computer? How come this shortcut can attach itself to every web browser on my computer? What is the next step I can do to resolve this problem? Is this kind of a virus?*

Comment: How come all of my browsers' shortcuts have been appended with that URL?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when that happens, you'll have to:

- reset the browser settings (or at least reset the startup websites on settings)
- go to the browser .exe, open it's properties and remove any flags that were added on the path.

Comment: The second step worked. How did it happen? I just checked that my Tor browser shortcut contains the same flags.

Comment: @lutjs I actually don't know how they do this, but these flags are a way to cheat these homepage settings, by automatically opening them through the shortucut

Comment: Although I found these flags, I couldn't save the changes. So I just deleted all these shortcuts and created the new ones. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I think you shoud uninstall these applications first.

Comment: I did. Yet the problem is how did it temper with all my browsers' shortcuts by appending the URL?